# How to check if a type is some particular generic type in a Scala macro?

Tags: scala, types, macros, scala-macros

I would like to perform AST traversal using macros, for AST types like:

```
  trait Node

  case class Root(children: Seq[Node]) extends Node {
    override def toString = s"Root(${children.size})"
  }
  case class Bi(left: Node, var right: Node) extends Node
  case class Leaf(id: String) extends Node
```

In the following code I can detect members of `T` which are of type `B` and create a function calling them. I would like to detect also members with type `Seq[B]` (and possible other containers containing `B`). I have tried constructing a type `TypeApply(Ident(TermName("Seq")), List(tq"$B"))`, which seems to work, however calling `.tpe` on this returns `null`, therefore I cannot call `<:<` on the result.

How can I do `f.asMethod.returnType <:< Seq[B]`?

```
  def walker[B, T <: B]: (T, B => Unit) => Unit = macro walker_impl[B, T]

  def walker_impl[B: c.WeakTypeTag, T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context): c.Expr[(T, B => Unit) => Unit] = {
    import c.universe._
    val T = weakTypeOf[T]
    val B = weakTypeOf[B]

    val seqType = TypeApply(Ident(TermName("Seq")), List(tq"$B"))
    val dive = T.decls.collect {
      case f if f.isMethod && f.asMethod.paramLists.isEmpty && f.asMethod.isGetter && f.asMethod.returnType <:< B =>
        q"t.$f"
      case f if f.isMethod && f.asMethod.paramLists.isEmpty &&
        f.asMethod.isGetter && f.asMethod.returnType <:< seqType.tpe
      =>
        q"t.$f" // TODO: decompose the seq

    }

    c.Expr[(T, B => Unit) => Unit](
      q"(t: $T, f: $B => Unit) => Seq(..$dive).map(f)"
    )
  }
```

Complete project can be see at https://github.com/OndrejSpanel/ScalaMacroMembers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a libray which is doing things like this, [AVSystem/scala-commons](https://github.com/AVSystem/scala-commons). Inspired by those sources I have implemented what I want in this way:

```
  val iterable = typeOf[Iterable[Any]]
  val iterableClass = iterable.typeSymbol
  def isSeqB(returnType: Type) = {
    returnType <:< iterable &&
    returnType.baseType(iterableClass).typeArgs.headOption.exists(_ <:< B)
  }

    case f if f.isMethod && f.asMethod.paramLists.isEmpty && f.asMethod.isGetter &&
      isSeqB(f.asMethod.returnType) =>
```

or simple

```
val iterableB = weakTypeOf[Iterable[B]]

case f if f.isMethod && f.asMethod.paramLists.isEmpty &&
  f.asMethod.isGetter && f.asMethod.returnType <:< iterableB =>
```